# Intermittent error: "A public action method 'index.php' was not found on controller '[x]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a SecurityController.Login method, which is an HTTPGET. Intermittently, in my IIS logs, I'm seeing one request for /Security/Login followed immediately (within 2 milliseconds, typically) by 3 requests for /Security/index.php.

Most of the time, I see only the first request for /Security/Login, which is correct, when someone comes to my site to log in. However, on occasion, I see the following 3 requests which, of course, cause an error: "A public action method 'index.php' was not found on controller '[x]'.

Any ideas how this "index.php" is being requested? index.php is not listed as a default document in IIS, and we have no instances of requests for index.php in our app, nor do we have any views or other documents that are named index.php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Any ideas how this "index.php" is being requested?
```

This could be bots, spiders and etc. I am using `Elmah` and very often I could found a lot of files with `*.php`. Many of them have strange headers, `user-agents` contain: Java, old browser versions, sometimes domain names of scanning sites or detecting CMS.